# How to fetch dates from database in Codeigniter and disable in the Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a table holiday_master which contains certain dates. I want to disable these dates in my Bootstrap datepicker. How can I write the Javascript code for this? Please correct me if the model and controller I have written is wrong? P.S: I am a beginner in programming track.

Controller:

```
public function fetchholiday()
    {
        $data['holiday']=$this->login_model->disableholiday();
        $this->load->view('leavehr');
    }
```

Model:

```
public function disableholiday()
    {
        $sql="select date from holiday_master";
        $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
        return $query->result();
    }
```

View:

```
<input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date"
<input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date">
```

Comment: Actually i am storing the holiday dates in db.i want to disable all those dates in db in bootstrap datepicker

Comment: We are here because we want to help, but SO is not a code-writing service. Break your problem up into pieces, and work on one at a time. Start with getting the dates out of the DB.  The Codeigniter docs are pretty good, here's the section on [database queries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html). Then look at how to disable those dates in your datepicker - [the docs show how to do that](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled). If you're having trouble, search here on SO, there are many many questions from ppl doing this.